# Send email when post status published wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post which is submitted by the visitor from front end. Visitor's submitted post status is pending.

Now when admin change the post status from pending to publish, I want to send an email to the author of this post. author email collected by custom field.

```
function send_mails_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status or 'trainee' !== get_post_type( $post ) )
        return;

    $author = get_post_meta( $post_id, $tr_user_reg_email, true );

    $body = sprintf( 'Hey there is a new entry!
        See <%s>',
        get_permalink( $post )
    );


    wp_mail( $author, 'New entry!', $body );
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_mails_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

This is what I'm trying. But this does not work. Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why do you have the "or 'publish' === $old_status? - aren't you only checking if something is published? not if something is removed from publish?

Comment: if it is a test site - you can try to see if you are even getting past you first if() - try to var_dump($author); - and should it not be $post->ID instead of $post_id?

Comment: this is a collected snippet, "or 'publish' === $old_status? is not required. only need to checked newly published post

Comment: also, you are not closing the function before you are adding the action

Comment: The function is closed, look at the bottom of code block, maybe i can't wrap the code block perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeh got my answer from [post status transition](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)

```
function on_publish_pending_post( $post ) {
// A function to perform actions when a post is published.

if ( "trainee" === get_post_type() ) { // check the custom post type

    $name   = get_the_title( $post->ID );

    // get email from custom field
    $author = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "tr_user_reg_email", true );

    $subject = "mail subject";

    $body    = "mail body";

    $headers = array (
        'From: "your name" <no-reply@your-domain.com>' ,
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(),
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' ,
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'
    );
    $headers = implode( "\r\n" , $headers );

    wp_mail( $author, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
}
add_action( "pending_to_publish", "on_publish_pending_post", 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any email restrictions from your hosting provider? Especially if it's a free hosting. If so, that may be the reason for it not working. If not, it may be just a small typo. It looks to me that you are also missing the {} for your if statement.

Answer (score -1):

add_action('transition_post_status', 'send_mails_on_publish', 10, 3);

function send_mails_on_publish($new_status, $old_status, $post)
{

```
if (
    'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status or
    'gestion_calendrier' !== get_post_type($post)
) {
    return;
} else {
    $headers = 'From: "Your Site <example@name.com>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: example@name.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $subscribers = get_users(array('role' => 'subscriber'));
    $emails      = array();
    foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber)
        $emails[] = $subscriber->user_email;

    $body = sprintf(
        'Hey there is a new entry!
        See <%s>',
        get_permalink($post)
    );

        wp_mail($emails, 'New entry!', $body,  $headers);
}
```

}